# How to load a data using ajax-php with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i got a link that performs a javascript function onclick

```
<input type='hidden' id='name'>
<a href='#' onclick='getUsers(1)'>Click here</a>
function getUsers(id){
  $('#name').val(id);
}
```

whenever i click the link i want to pass the '1' to be the value of the hidden input type.

after that i want to perform an ajax to use the value of the hidden input type for my mysql query.

would that be possible?

Thank you

Comment: You have to search for this in stackoverflow 1000's of answer you can get for `ajax`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#name').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            // your code here
        });
});
```